# Visual Studio & SQL Management Studio: How to revert Ctrl+Tab behaviour to normal after using Microsoft Narrator?

Tags: visual-studio, ssms, narrator

By default, in Visual Studio and in SQL Server Management Studio, Ctrl+Tab opens a navigation popup which lists all the open windows. The idea is that you can press Tab multiple times while keeping Ctrl pressed; as soon as you release Ctrl, the navigation popup disappears and the selected document is activated.

Unfortunately, as soon as you ever run Microsoft Narrator (text-to-speech reader), this behaviour changes. The popup no longer disappears when you release Ctrl; it waits until you press Enter to select a document. While I can appreciate this behaviour may be reasonable for blind people who are actually reliant on Narrator, I find it rather irritating that the behaviour has changed permanently and that the old behaviour doesn't return even if I stop using Narrator completely.

Is there any way to restore the old behaviour so that it doesn't wait for an extra Enter keypress anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be patient and it magically starts reverting to normal after not using Narrator or Speech Recognition for a month or so.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but still an issue with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2008 when Speech recognition is running on Windows 7 (32bit Ultimate).

Worse yet, there is no fix per se. As a workaraound, I exit Speech Recognition, and then ctrl-tab behaves as expected.

I saw a post for changing Narrator settings, but none of the settings in Narrator (text to speech) have any effect on the issue.